# How do I control Token Response Expiry time for google API access

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-oauth-java-client

I have problem extending the standard one hour for validity of google access token.
One part of my code is getting authorization from the user, using the `GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow` as per Google recommendation. This works fine and gives me a TokenResponse that I persist to be used in an other part of the application where the user is not connected.

As per Google documentation, I thought that the `"offline"` access type in the flow would enable the TokenResponse to be usable as longer as the user doesnt revoke it. But apparently when I use this TokenReponse just after the user authorization, it works fine but when I use it after more than one hour, I get an "invalid credentials" sent back by Google.

Here is the code which creates the TokenResponse once the user has authorized it :

```
private HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
private JacksonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

private static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {

        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    } catch (GeneralSecurityException | IOException e) {
        logger.info(String.format("Raised Exception while getting GoogleNetHttpTransport : %s", e.getMessage()));
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, APP_ID, APP_SECRET,
            Collections.singleton(CalendarScopes.CALENDAR_READONLY)).setAccessType("offline").build();
}
@RequestMapping(value = Uris.GOOGLERD)
public ModelAndView googleCallBack(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(value = "state", required = false) String state,
        @RequestParam(value = "code", required = false) String code,
        @RequestParam(value = "error", required = false) String error, Model model) {
    DynSubscriber dynSubscriber = (DynSubscriber) request.getSession().getAttribute("dynSubscriber");
    ModelAndView toReturn = new ModelAndView("confirmation");
    toReturn.addObject("buttonLabel", "Accueil");

    try {

        AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest tokenRequest = flow.newTokenRequest(code);
        TokenResponse tr = tokenRequest.setRedirectUri(request.getRequestURL().toString()).execute();


        // Json Conversion of Token Response for future use
        StringWriter jsonTrWriter = new StringWriter();
        JsonGenerator generator = JSON_FACTORY.createJsonGenerator(jsonTrWriter);
        generator.serialize(tr);
        generator.flush();
        generator.close();


        //Persists google access info 
        dynSubOp.setSPConnexionInfo(dynSubscriber, jsonTrWriter.toString(), DynServiceProviderType.GOOGLECAL);
        toReturn.addObject("message","Agenda Google autorisé");

    } catch (IOException | DynServicesException e) {
        logger.error(String.format("Exception raised in googleCallBack for subscriber %s : %s", dynSubscriber.buildFullName(), e.getMessage()),e);
        toReturn.addObject("message", "Problème lors du processus d'autorisation google");
    }

    return toReturn;
}
}
```

And here is the offline code which uses this TokenReponse :

```
private com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar calendarConnection;


public DynGoogleCalendarRetriever(String subid, String connectionInformation)
        throws CalendarConnectionNotAuthorizedException {


    TokenResponse tr;
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        tr = JSON_FACTORY.fromString(connectionInformation, TokenResponse.class);

        Credential c = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(tr);
        calendarConnection = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, c)
                .build();
    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        logger.error(String.format("Failure creating the credentials for subscriber id %s", subid), e);
        throw new CalendarConnectionNotAuthorizedException(String.format(
                "Failure creating the credentials for subscriber id %s", subid), e);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was already answered in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777842/how-to-get-offline-token-and-refresh-token-and-auto-refresh-access-to-google-api).
To get the refresh token that enables what I want, I need to build the flow with a approval_prompt=force parameter (`builder.setApprovalPrompt("force")`)

As per the comment, this requires the offline access which is done in the flow initialization.

A complement however : the offline code in my question doesn't work as such although I copied and pasted it from google documentation (probably an older version). The Credential needs to use its Builder object.

Here is the fully functionnal offline code :

```
    TokenResponse tr;
    try {
        HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        tr = JSON_FACTORY.fromString(connectionInformation, TokenResponse.class);

        Credential c = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setClientSecrets(APP_ID, APP_SECRET).build().setFromTokenResponse(tr);

        calendarConnection = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, c)
                .build();
    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        logger.error(String.format("Failure creating the credentials for subscriber id %s", subid), e);
        throw new CalendarConnectionNotAuthorizedException(String.format(
                "Failure creating the credentials for subscriber id %s", subid), e);
    }
```

Comment: That's not quote correct. You may well need to force approval for other reasons, but that doesn't affect whether or not you win a refresh token. To get a refresh token you need to request *offline* access.