# Oauth 2.0 issues with refresh token PHP

Tags: php, oauth, token

i dont seem to get the refresh token when i call the access token? Here is the code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$redirect = filter_var(URL,
FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect);
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force"); 
$client->setState('offline');

var_dump($client->getAccessToken());
```

And this is what i get from it:

```
string(163) "{"access_token":"","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3599,"created":1111111111}"
```

Why dont i get the refresh token?

Comment: Is it really blank?  access_token is blank?

Comment: No its not, I just removed it.

Comment: You get a token that is still valid, and that should be all that matters. (AFAIK OAuth spec does not require that you get a _different_ token each time you ask for one.)

Comment: I solved the issue. The error was: 

$client->setState('offline');

It should be : $client->setAccessType('offline');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One thing you should be careful about: a refresh token is returned (in
>   addition to the access token) only when the user gives consent
>   explicitly for the requested scopes. Basically, when the approval page
>   is shown. All subsequent flows will only return an access token.

You are missing

```
$client->setApprovalPrompt("force");
```

[How to get offline token and refresh token and auto-refresh access to Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13777842/how-to-get-offline-token-and-refresh-token-and-auto-refresh-access-to-google-api)

Comment: Thanks for the help. However this does not solve the issue. I still only get the access token:



string(163) "    {"access_token":"ya29.FgFml_QHQMORS0GqtL7kCZ3PO-gqm4fJOCj1hC5IYdJGptbGKtIBwrdnsWNauqFPIsXOgj1iuy3CQw","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"created":1423558200}"

Comment: Partly this was the error. Thanks alot for the help =)